# How to configure Perforce connection parameters using p4 commandLine?

Tags: perforce

How to set specific **user name**, r**emote server address** using *p4 command line*, so that these values are reflected when viewing the information using `p4 info` ?

I know if I use the p4V client, and create the connection once, p4 info will automatically get updated. But I don't want to use p4V, and want to do it all from command Line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link lists all the Perforce environment variables: [Environment Variables](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v14.2/cmdref/envars.html)

Open the command line, and use the p4 set command [`p4 set`](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v14.2/cmdref/p4_set.html) to configure the fields you want to set.

For example,

1. To Configure the USER NAME

   p4 set P4USER="USER_NAME"
2. To Configure the remote server address

   p4 set P4PORT="ADDRESS:PORT"